# In VIM, using . (dot) command as an operator?

Tags: vim

In VIM, the *-powerful-* <kbd>•</kbd> command *(the dot command)* is used to repeat the last action..

But since it is actually defined as a **command** not an **operator**, it is not possible to combine it with a motion since only operator are meant to be used with a motion. *(Cf. http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif for a refresher)*

Is it possible to actually use the *dot command* (when possible) as an operator?

Here is a little use case: I have some lines, and I append to the first one a word. Then I can type <kbd>j •</kbd> to do the same to the next line.. And if I wanted to do this for the first ten lines I should repeat this 8 more times...

If I do <kbd>8 • j</kbd> it will repeat 8 times the modification on the same line, then go down one line..

If I do <kbd>8 j •</kbd> it will actually jump down 8 lines and then do it once.

In fact this is obviously the expected *(and correct)* behaviour, but is there a way to have the <kbd>.</kbd> behave like an operator?

*Thank you..*

**Edit:** I found a way to achieve that behaviour based on **ephemient** answer.

In summary just to use the <kbd>•</kbd> in the command mode with `:norm`

- On the first line, press <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> to enter visual block selection.
- Navigate down to the last line (<kbd>8 j</kbd>).

At this time, the <kbd>$</kbd> and the <kbd>A</kbd>ppend is not really needed since it is actually registered *'inside'* the <kbd>•</kbd> command. Indeed, the necessity of the <kbd>•</kbd> is actually to use that last modification and avoid to retype it (particularly useful if it was something more complicated like <kbd>ci "</kbd>)

- Press <kbd>:</kbd> to enter the **command mode** and then type `norm .`<kbd>⏎</kbd>

This seems to work for me..

*Remark, when entering in **command mode** the following text* `:'<,'>` *is already present, but I typed the above afterwards, like this* `:'<,'>norm .`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- On the first line, press <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> to enter visual block selection.
- Navigate down to the last line (<kbd>8j</kbd>).
- Press <kbd>$</kbd> to move the cursor to the end of (all) lines.
- Press <kbd>A</kbd> (capital A), type to append your word, then <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave visual block insert mode.
- The word is now appended to all selected lines.

You can find other suggestions on the [Vim wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Inserting_text_in_multiple_lines).

Comment: Hi.. I actually just found how to do that following this track.. For better lisibility I will write a post using your formatting... StackOverflow advises me to edit the question rather than to answer myself... But you can also add this workaround so I can tick your answer..

Answer (score 1):

As [this thread on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/429917/repeat-last-normal-mode-command-including-moves-in-vim) suggests, it is unfortunately not possible in vanilla Vim (the easy way).

You can use the [repmo.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2174) plugin if you want to use `.` like this.

Otherwise, I'd use macros and `@@` to repeat the last macro used.

Comment: In fact I knew that this was possible with macros, but in that case the move (eg. `j`) should also be in part of the macro in order to behave as stated. Otherwise the macro seems to behave exactly like the `.` (at least in that particular case).

Comment: By the way, thank you for the other thread, I searched for a similar question here but found nothing... In fact the other question was the same but the answers seem not really helpful..